# Buttons are not visible in datatables 1.10.9

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I just updated tabletools to buttons with new version of datatable extenstion, but i could not able to show\see buttons for xls, pdf etc.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/global/plugins/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/global/plugins/datatables/media/js/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/global/plugins/datatables/extensions/Buttons/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/global/plugins/datatables/extensions/Buttons/js/buttons.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/global/plugins/datatables/extensions/Select/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/global/plugins/datatables/extensions/ColReorder/js/dataTables.colReorder.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/global/plugins/datatables/media/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/global/plugins/datatables/extensions/Buttons/css/buttons.bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/global/plugins/datatables/extensions/Select/css/select.bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/global/plugins/datatables/extensions/ColReorder/css/colReorder.bootstrap.min.css"/>
```

I have initialize datatable as below,

```
var table = $('#inventoryorders_table').DataTable({

buttons: [ 'copy', 'csv', 'excel' ],
"select": {
        style: 'single'
        },
"colReorder": true,
});
```

i can see select, colreorder everything work fine, but could not see buttons,
I am using bootstrap styling.

What is wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: you _do_ have [`dom: 'Bfrtip'`](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/simple.html) or similar...?

Comment: As per new version, its not required, i can see search, length, pagination etc, but not buttons

Answer (score 2):

To show [buttons](http://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/) buttons :

1. Add `B` to your `dom` option -> **http://jsfiddle.net/6cja01fv/** (try comment out `dom: 'Bfrtip'`)
2. Direct insertion, add `table.buttons().container()` to somewhere, for example `table.buttons().container().prependTo($(table.table().container()))` -> **http://jsfiddle.net/6gkqydbr/**

Answer (score 1):

It depends on many other external cdn,

```
//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.0.3/js/buttons.flash.min.js
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.min.js
//cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.18/build/pdfmake.min.js
//cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.18/build/vfs_fonts.js
//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.0.3/js/buttons.html5.min.js
//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.0.3/js/buttons.print.min.js
```